# "make: arm-eabi-gcc: command not found"

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, android-ndk

I installed all the stuff I listed here: [Building a custom ROM on Debian 7.1 (Wheezy) - Ginux](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2474543) and got the results given below.

I later installed binutils:i386, which uninstalled most of that stuff and installed a 78 MB package, which I assume replaces a lot of it, but, I got the same results.

```
$ echo $PATH /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/storage/software/android/custom/repo
$ echo $CROSS_COMPILE /storage/software/android/custom/sources/android-lgp769v21b/linux-x86/toolchain/arm-eabi-4.4.3/bin/arm-eabi-
$
$ make ARCH=arm clean
make: arm-eabi-gcc: Command not found
clean
$
$ ls /storage/software/android/custom/sources/android-lgp769v21b/linux-x86/toolchain/arm-eabi-4.4.3/bin/
arm-eabi-addr2line  arm-eabi-cpp        arm-eabi-gcov    arm-eabi-nm       arm-eabi-run
arm-eabi-ar         arm-eabi-g++        arm-eabi-gdb     arm-eabi-objcopy  arm-eabi-size
arm-eabi-as         arm-eabi-gcc        arm-eabi-gdbtui  arm-eabi-objdump  arm-eabi-strings
arm-eabi-c++        arm-eabi-gcc-4.4.3  arm-eabi-gprof   arm-eabi-ranlib   arm-eabi-strip
arm-eabi-c++filt    arm-eabi-gccbug     arm-eabi-ld      arm-eabi-readelf  xmlwf
$
$ file /storage/software/android/custom/sources/android-lgp769v21b/linux-x86/toolchain/arm-eabi-4.4.3/bin/arm-eabi-gcc
ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.8, not stripped
$
```

Why would I get this on a 64-bit machine with the 32-bit development package installed, or, how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The Android platform build environment is self-contained besides the pre-requisites laid out on the AOSP [Initializing a Build Environment](http://source.android.com/source/initializing.html) page.

The toolchain is either in the prebuilts folder or it's built from source. Because there are multiple architectures supported in AOSP, you need to force the build to use one toolchain.

Do this with the *lunch* command...

```
lunch
lunch 1
lunch aosp_arm
```

... and then issue your *make* command.

Answer (score 0):

"Command not found" sounds like a path issue. Check to make sure that the toolchain is in your PATH environment variable.

Comment: i believe that was supposed to be the purpose of $CROSS_COMPILE, right? if so, then it should not be necessary for $PATH, but, i noticed that at some point i appear to have exported it to path as well. either way, that does not appear to be the issue. thanks.